# How to open Youtube video on modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube-api, magnific-popup

I need to adjust my code so that the video is played in the modal that is opened when the user clicks on it.

This code was implemented in a modal that was to display images.

I use JS: https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

**PHP:**

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=ID';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$ns = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$elementos = $xml->xpath('//a:entry');
$conteudo = $elementos[0];

$videos_pagina = "12";
$page = isset($_GET['pagina'])?intval($_GET['pagina']-1):0;
$total_paginas = ceil(count($elementos)/$videos_pagina);

    if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && is_numeric($_GET['pagina'])) {
        $pagina = (int) $_GET['pagina'];
    } else {
        $pagina = 1;
    }
    if ($pagina > $total_paginas) {
        $pagina = $total_paginas;
    }
    if ($pagina < 1) {
        $pagina = 1;
    }

$offset = ($pagina - 1) * $videos_pagina;
$range = 3;
$prevpage = $pagina - 1;
$nextpage = $pagina + 1;
$anterior = $baseurl."/videos/pagina/".$prevpage;
$proxima = $baseurl."/videos/pagina/".$nextpage;
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="about-section pb30">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                foreach (array_slice($elementos, $page*$videos_pagina, $videos_pagina) as $item) {
                    $media = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
                    $yt = $item->children('http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015');
                    $miniatura = $media->group->thumbnail->attributes()->url->__toString();
                    $titulo = $item->title;
                    $url_embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$yt->videoId;
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="gallery_item">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-circle-rounded w100" src="<?php echo $miniatura; ?>" alt="<?php echo $titulo; ?>">
                        <div class="gallery_overlay"><a href="#" class="icon popup-img" ><span class="fa fa-play"></span></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="gallery_item" align="center"><br>
                    <button type="button" <?php if ($pagina > 1) { }else{ echo "disabled"; } ?> onclick="location.href='<?php echo $anterior; ?>';" class="btn btn-lg btn-thm">Página anterior</button>
                    <button type="button" <?php if ($pagina != $total_paginas) { }else{ echo "disabled"; } ?> onclick="location.href='<?php echo $proxima; ?>';" class="btn btn-lg btn-thm">Próxima página</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Currently when the user clicks on the video he opens the modal, however I need the video to be loaded.

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily embed or place the YouTube video inside a Bootstrap modal like you do on the normal web pages. Just get the code to embed the video from YouTube site and place it inside the .modal-body element. But there is small problem; the YouTube video doesn't stop automatically when you close the modal window. It will still play in the background.

To solve this problem you can simply toggle the url value of the YouTube's video iframe src attribute dynamically using the jQuery. Let's try out the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example of Embedding YouTube Video inside Bootstrap Modal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .modal-content iframe{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url
    and store it in a variable */
    var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');
    
    /* Assign empty url value to the iframe src attribute when
    modal hide, which stop the video playing */
    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');
    });
    
    /* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src
    attribute when modal is displayed again */
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
    
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! Can you help me to implement this in my current code? I honestly don't know how to customize with these jquery codes.

Comment: The problem is that there are several videos, they are displayed with php repetition parameters. I think that in that case there would be a problem using that code, right? Perhaps you would like to have the video ID in the link to open the popup.